# Maya commands get all locators

Tags: python, maya

How can I retrieve all the locators in a maya file with maya commands. My current code returns locators but for some reason includes lights as well.

```
locators = cmds.ls(type=('locator'), l=True) or []
transforms = map(lambda x: cmds.listRelatives(x, allDescendents=True, fullPath=True, parent=True)[0], locators)
```

outputs:

```
[u'|Ground_masterCtrl', u'|Monster_masterCtrl', u'|VRayLightRect1', u'|VRayLightRect2']
```

[image]

I want it to return me just the locators...

```
[u'|Ground_masterCtrl', u'|Monster_masterCtrl']
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain what's happening here, I'm going to assume that the VRayLightRect node is a custom plugin node, which happens to derive from `MPxLocatorNode`. As a result, technically speaking the base class of that light rect is actually a locator node.

You have 1 of two options to filter those nodes out.

Option 1: use the exactType instead of type:

```py
locators = cmds.ls(exactType=('locator'), l=True) or []
```

Option 2: use the excludeType flag to remove the light rect:

```py
locators = cmds.ls(type=('locator'), excludeType=('VRayLightRect'), l=True) or []
```